# How does the て form work here?

Tags: grammar, verbs, て-form

So I've been told that when you use the て form of verbs in a sentence, the last verb is the one that tells you in what tense the sentence is, but I found this sentence:

> 目を合わせて逸らさない、というのはそれで真摯に見える。内心でどう思っていても、少なくとも見た目は。

So according to what I said, the translation for that first part would be "To not make eye contact and to not look away", but that doesn't make any sense in this situation, because the person is trying to look as sincere as possible.

My question is, how do I know if the last verb is influencing the previous verbs or not?

Comment: Are you thinking of "affirmative or negative" as part of the concept of "tense"?

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. Does the last verb influence the previous ones just when it's a tense (like past, present/future) and when it's affirmative or negative they stand on their own?

Comment: Yes, tense refers to the time frame of the word, and affirmative / negative is separate.